Is it possible to forward credentials to a Remote Desktop session?
I would like to achieve something similar to SSH agent forwarding with Windows 10 and Remote Desktop.
Let's say I have some secret on my host, either in an environment variable or in Windows Credential Manager. I would like this secret to be available to me on a remote machine after I've logged into it with Remote Desktop.
I have found the remoteapplicationexpandcmdline option here but I couldn't find any further documentation, and I'm not sure if it's even relevant to this problem. I tried it in my .RDP file with no success
Somewhat related is this answer which states that the SSH server available on Windows does not support agent forwarding.
Is that or something similar possible?
